# HTML5 data, arrays and .push - weird conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

So I'm trying to figure out why when I push a value to a parent object, child objects with that.

html:

```
<div id="parent" class="things" data-tallest="[]">
  <div id="child1" class="things" data-tallest="[]">
    I'm a child
  </div>
  <div id="child2" class="things" data-tallest="[]">
    I'm another child
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
somearray = ["child1", "child2"]
$(".things").data("tallest",[])
for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++) {
  tocheck = somearray[i]
  newarray = $("#"+tocheck).parent().data("tallest")
  newarray.push(20);
  $(tocheck).parent().data("tallest",newarray)
}

console.log("Child 1 'tallest': "+$("#child1").data("tallest"));
```

See this fiddle (problem is noted in console log):

http://jsfiddle.net/cTY3H/3/

What SHOULD happen is I iterate through the array and twice push "20" onto the parent object `$("#parent")`'s data-tallest array. It should result in [20,20]. Instead, both of the child objects get the value [20,20] pushed into their array instead. The child objects should never get anything assigned to them.

Edit: clarification

Any guesses?

Comment: Congratulations to you, @thenewseattle, for the least helpful and most judgemental answer I've ever gotten on Stack Overflow. A few points of clarification:

1 - This is not a homework assignment. I'm seeing bizarre behavior when I assign a value using jQuery's .data() method. I can't find any documentation from jQuery or elsewhere that explains why a child object would get a data value assigned to its parent.

2 - I've provided a jsfiddle that clearly and cleanly reproduces the error. At no point in that javascript is a value assigned to #child1, but it gets a value anyway.

Comment: Because in the real situation, the data is loaded from a Rails backend and written and read by numerous different scripts. It can be updated by a number of different sources (including Faye), so it's acting as a variable storage that is attached to a specific object on in the DOM, objects which get created and destroyed frequently. Using the HTML5 data-* attributes for initial variable load and then updating them seems to be the right method.

Comment: That isn't relevant here. Unless you can explain why using jQuery's `.parent().data()` methods assigns values to not only a parent object but all child objects, I don't think you can help me. I'll just find another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in line 1 of the above javascript. According to @jfriend00 and @charlietfl, my attempt to clear the stored values with:

```
$(".things").data("tallest",[])
```

Resulted in all the .things objects getting the *same* array, so any change to one changed them all.

See a better explanation at: [jQuery data method pushes data to child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039663/jquery-data-method-pushes-data-to-child-objects)

Answer (score 3):

Your array has only one item, change:

```
somearray = ["child1, child2"]
```

to:

```
var somearray = ["child1", "child2"];
```

Comment: Yeah, typo in my example. Sadly, that doesn't quite do it. The question is why the child objects are getting the data value that should only have been pushed into parent.