# jQuery data method pushes data to child objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seeing really weird behavior with jQuery's .data() function. When I assign a value to a parent element, it's children also get assigned that data value.

#### html:

```
<div id="parent" class="things" data-tallest="[]">
  <div id="child1" class="things" data-tallest="[]">
    I'm a child
  </div>
  <div id="child2" class="things" data-tallest="[]">
    I'm another child
  </div>
</div>
```

#### js:

```
somearray = ["child1", "child2"]
$(".things").data("tallest",[])
for (var i = 0; i < somearray.length; i++) {
  tocheck = somearray[i]
  newarray = $("#"+tocheck).parent().data("tallest")
  newarray.push(20);
  $(tocheck).parent().data("tallest",newarray)
}

console.log("Correct: parent 'tallest': "+$("#parent").data("tallest"));
console.log("Problem: child1 'tallest': "+$("#child1").data("tallest"));
```

See this fiddle (problem is noted in console log):

http://jsfiddle.net/cTY3H/5/

#### What SHOULD happen:

1. All values stored in any object's data-tallest variable are cleared
2. The loop iterates through the array and pushes "20" onto the parent object `$("#parent")`'s *data-tallest* array
3. `$("#parent").data("tallest")` should equal [20,20] - it does.
4. However, `$("#child1").data("tallest")` == [20,20]
5. At no point are child objects getting anything assigned to .data("tallest"), so I don't know why this is happening.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you pushing 20 onto an array? What's `$(tocheck)` supposed to be targeting since there's no element `$('child1')` or `$('child2')` (you left off the `#`).

Comment: FYI, there's really no reason to have the `data-tallest="[]"` in your HTML markup since you're initializing it all in JS.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Actually, when these get initially drawn, the backend can insert values there. The initial state of the document is loaded from the Rails backend, and then various things can cause this function to reinitialize the 'tallest' value. This is just the simplified version, but with enough pieces that if I was doing something stupid you guys could find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize all .`things` items to have the exact same reference to the same empty array.  So, when you modify one, they all change because they all point to the same array.  Remember arrays are assigned and retrieved by reference.  So, this line:

```
$(".things").data("tallest",[])
```

Is assigning a reference to the exact same array to every `.things` object.  Change one and they all change which explains your output.

---

You can fix it and simplify it like this:

```
// initialize all things to have their own empty array for data
$(".things").each(function() {
    $(this).data("tallest", []);
});
["#child1", "#child2"].each(function() {
    // get reference to parent data array and push a value onto it
    $(this).parent().data("tallest").push(20);
    // you don't have to set it back because the array is by reference so already changed
});
```

---

When manipulating arrays, you also have to be very careful because arrays are passed around by reference.  So, when you get the data from one place and modify it you are modifying the original because fetching the array did not make a copy, it just had a reference.  I don't think that's biting you here, but it very easily could if you tried to take the data from one element, modify it and assign it to a different element.

Comment: I dind't notice the `tocheck` problem...that line isn't needed anyway since array stored in `data()` is being updated already by reference

Comment: @charlietfl - I thought the assignment maybe isn't need to, except maybe the first time when data isn't actually in jQuery's javascript yet - only in the attribute.  Then, I think it would have to be set back, but with jsFiddle down I can't test that easily.

Comment: look here  , I removed last line, and used `each` to create inital array http://plnkr.co/edit/oS6BkOTcb8kuilDMTmTJ  Have been working a lot with angular.js...this stuff happen all the time in that framework. Everthing is bult on wanting inheritance for data binding

Comment: @charlietfl - yeah, I realized they were already initalizing all data to `[]` to it will always be a reference to no assignment back is needed.  I've updated my simplified version.

Comment: yup...if OP had just left the markup `[]` wouldn't have happened...but good to understand why it happend

Comment: @charlietfl - I figured it out.  All `.things` are initialized to the same empty array.  So modifying one changed them all (they are all references to the same array).

Comment: well they would be when stored in different locations, a reference would be set into `data` no? But as I suggested in my answer they are the same array for sure

Comment: I think we're saying same thing...my terminology gets sloppy sometimes

Comment: Thank you so much. I hadn't realized that arrays were all initialized by reference. This has really helped me out, I was pulling my hair out in the (much more complicated) actual implementation where I was doing this. I thought I was initializing an empty array for each object, not a single array that all the objects would then share. If I could buy @charlietfl and jfriend00 a beer I would.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
$(".things").data("tallest",[])
```

You are putting the same array into each element's data. Thus by prototypical inheritance, they all share references to the same array.

Change to:

```
$(".things").each(function(){
    $(this).data("tallest",[])
})
```

Each has it's own unique array

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/oS6BkOTcb8kuilDMTmTJ)**</kbd>

Simple object reference example:

```
var a=[];
var b=a;
b.push('foo');
alert(a[0]); //foo
```